# Android GCM notification doesn't redirects to intended activity when app is in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Hi I have created a notification intent as follows

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


int notification_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Everything works perfectly if the app is closed. But if app is running in background, it just pops last opened activity from background to foreground. I want to go to exact page received in the data.
Someone help, I tried many combinations of `FLAGS`.

Comment: try this   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

Comment: Add your manifest code for activity which you want to start on notification click.

Comment: Please post your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @rahul pointed out if you change `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `Intent.FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY_TASK` it works as I required, but one problem I founded is that if you have multiple notifications in the notification bar only one action will work. When tapped on the remaining ones it will just clear from there, no actions will work. The following is the correct solution -

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Calling `setFlags()` twice like this overwrites the flags with the second call. You will end up with only `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` set, which isn't what you want. Either use `addFlags()` instead of `setFlags()` or put both flags in the argument to `setFlags()` like this: `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Answer (score 4):

Just a work around try this

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Worked. But Studio show warning in the line `Must be on or more of:PendingIntent.......`

Comment: You should pass PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT at the place of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK because this Intent Flag is not recommended for PendingIntent.getActivity method.

Comment: Passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_...` to a call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` is wrong. This call accepts  `PendingIntent` flags, not `Intent` flags.

Comment: Thanks for insight @DavidWasser voted up for the useful tip

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
```

Try this in your intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** 
If this flag is set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: Not working..by setting the above flags, currently opened activity is displayed. What I want is get call on onCreate every time when I tap on notification whether app is in background or foreground.l

Comment: Have you added android:exported="true" in your android manifest inside activity tag which is supposed to be opened after tapping notification ?

Answer (score 0):

Add flag for clear existing tasks and starting new task.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is irrelevant and redundant if you specify `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` you **must also use** `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. It even says this in the documentation.